# Solr: transform a comma-delimited field during data import

Tags: solr

I'm working with Solr 3.5.0. I am importing from a JDBC data source and have a delimited field that I would like split into individual values.  I'm using the `RegexTransformer` but my field isn't being split.

### sample value

```
Bob,Carol,Ted,Alice
```

### data-config.xml

```xml
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource driver="..." />
  <document>
    <entity name="ent"
            query="SELECT id,names FROM blah"
            transformer="RegexTransformer">
      <field column="id" />
      <field column="names" splitBy="," />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

### schema.xml

```xml
<schema name="mytest" version="1.0">
  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"
               omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="integer" indexed="false" stored="true"
           multiValued="false" required="true" />
    <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
           multiValued="true" required="true" />
  </fields>
</schema>
```

When I search *:* I get a result `doc` element like this:

```xml
<doc>
  <int name="id">22</int>
  <arr name="names">
    <str>Bob,Carol,Ted,Alice</str>
  </arr>
</doc>
```

I was hoping to get this instead:

```xml
<doc>
  <int name="id">22</int>
  <arr name="names">
    <str>Bob</str>
    <str>Carol</str>
    <str>Ted</str>
    <str>Alice</str>
  </arr>
</doc>
```

It's quite possible I misunderstand the [`RegexTransformer`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer) section of the wiki.  I've tried changing my delimiter and I've tried using a different field for the parts (as shown in the wiki)...

```
<field column="name" splitBy="," sourceColName="names" />
```

...but that resulted in an empty `name` field.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your updated field definition is the correct one. The field names must correspond in your `data-import.xml` and your `schema.xml`. Are you sure you reindexed after the change? Did you get any error messages in the solr log?

Comment: Yes, I even deleted the index directory to be sure.  All the log statements are going to the console and I haven't seen anything there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914483/solr-facet-multiple-words-with-comma-separated-values/9915079#9915079 This answer from another thread worked for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I handled a similar issue by creating a fieldtype in the schema file:

```
<fieldType name="commaDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=",\s*" />
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then I applied that type to the field to the data field like:

```
<field name="features" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Comment: No matter what I do I just can't get this to work. :( I've copied this and the original post exactly and still my field comes through as one field with a comma-separated string value. What am I missing??

Comment: The data will still be stored as a comma delimited string, but you should be able to query it as individual values.  If your field name is "names" with values "bill, bob, ted", it will store them as the comma delimited string, but will index them as individual values.  You can then query like names: "ted".

Comment: What is the difference with setting type="text_ws"?

Comment: That would depend on what you defined "text_ws" as.  If you look at my example, I define a type of "commaDelimited" that uses regex to split the field.  Here are the types included in Solr:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr.  "text_ws" is not an included field type.

Answer (score 2):

Your database column is called `names` while the Solr field is called `name` (Notice the missing `s`). One solution is to use the following in your DIH config and then re-index.

```
<field name="name" column="names" splitBy=","/>
```

Comment: OP seems to have corrected this in his updated definition. Also your code has a stray comma.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting transformer="RegexTransformer" before the query statement also you have an error

```
   transformer="RegexTransformer">
```

you need to remove the '>'

Answer (score 1):

You can use transformer="RegexTransformer" and also you can use javascript for splitting the value.

```
<script><![CDATA[

function stringtoarray(row) {
 var value=row.get('names');

 if(value !="" && value !=null) {   
   name_arr=value.split(",");
   row.put('name',name_arr);
   return row;
 }
}
]]>
</script>
```

and add the `transformer="script:stringtoarray"` to the entity field

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple values in your field, such as -

actors":["Chris Pratt, Vin Diesel, Bradley Cooper, Zoe Saldana"], you can create new fieldtype in schema.xml as-

```
<fieldType name="search_field_type" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*,\s*" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25" />
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <field name="actors" type="search_field_type" uninvertible="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

data-config

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource  type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/movie" user="postgres" password="postgres" />
    <document >
      <entity name="moviedata"  pk="rank" query="SELECT * from moviedata" transformer="RegexTransformer">
        <field column="actors"  splitBy="," name="actors"/>
      </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

After importing data, your field will be-

"actors":["Chris Pratt"," Vin Diesel"," Bradley Cooper"," Zoe Saldana"]