# Extract text from multiple files using tika and dataimporthandler

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dataimporthandler

I'm using dataimporthandler to import data from SqlServer and tika for extracting text from file.

I figured out how to extract text from file and put it in field when there is one file. But I run into a problem when it goes to extract text from multiple files.

From database I get document with fields like 'title', 'body' etc. and list of file locations: 'file1.pdf, file2.pdf, file3.pdf' (varchar(max) - comma separated list of locations). When list has only 1 element it's easy and I'm doing it like this:

```xml
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" name="bin"/>
 <dataSource  type="JdbcDataSource" name="sql"
              driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=db;Integrated Security=False;User Id=uss;Password=qwerty;" />
 <document>
    <entity name="content" query="select * from content" 
            transformer="RegexTransformer" dataSource="sql">
        <field column="id" name="id"/>
        <field column="title" name="title"/>
        <field column="body" name="body"/>

        <field column="attachmenttext" name="attachmenttext"/>
        <entity name='tik' processor="TikaEntityProcessor" 
                url="${content.filelocation}" dataSource="bin" format="text">
            <field column="text" name="attachmenttext" />
        </entity> 
    </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Is there any way to tell tika that it should extract text from more than one file?

I'm using latest Apache Solr version (4.10.3)

schema.xml (part with fields)

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="body" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="attachmenttext" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

Comment: Would you look up your schema.xml? It could also be that the field named `attachmenttext` is not multivalued there. In that case only the text of the first attachment would be stored.

Comment: @cheffe thanks for suggestion! I checked it and attachmenttetxt is a multivcalue field. I posted my schema.xml

Comment: hm, I am missing something. Your are selecting * from content. One of its' columns is named filelocation(?) and the type of that column is ... ? Or is this in reality a subselect from some other table? Or is that column a nested list or something like that? Or is it a varchar with a concatenated list of fileLocations? Or ... I just do not get, how you come from one column to a list of files :)

Comment: Oh, maybe I missed that: filelocation is varchar(max) and it's comma separated list of filelocations

Comment: I have never tried it and cannot produce a sample fast, but you should try to split the content of attachementtext by adding `splitBy="," sourceColumn="attachementtext"` that works in conjunction with the `RegexTransformer` as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914483/solr-facet-multiple-words-with-comma-separated-values

Comment: The problem is in telling tika that filelocation is multivalued and it should be splitted. Then tika should extract multiple files into attachmenttext