# CSV field in Solr

Tags: arrays, csv, drupal, solr

So I've got a comma separated value field (technically a textfield, but all of the values will be formatted as CSV) in Drupal which will be submitted to an Apache Solr query document.

The values will be a list of keywords, for example something like this (but not necessarily this):

```
productid, nameofproduct, randomattribute1, randomattribute2, etc, etc2
```

How would I best get Solr to process each of these? Do I need to create a separate string field for each of them, or is there anyway for Apache Solr to process what is essentially an array of values as a single field?

I'm not seeing any documentation on the dynamic fields that allows this, but it seems like a common enough use case that it would be usable.

So in short, is there anyway to use a field of CSV in Solr, or do I have to separate each value into a separate field for indexing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for arrays, see 'multiValued' attribute of field. More on field attributes [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml). It is difficult to say what is right schema from your question. See

> /Solr_Directory/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml

The file can be used as a starting point and contains various combinations of fields.

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446184/solr-transform-a-comma-delimited-field-during-data-import) question. The answer shows how to split string by comma and store.