# Solr8: Index and query comma separated values

Tags: csv, solr

I use Solr 8.10.1 and I'm trying to index and query a field that contains multiple comma separated values: "test,hello,stack"
I tried both solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446184/solr-transform-a-comma-delimited-field-during-data-import) (although these are for Solr 3.5.0), and neither return any results when I use query:

http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/select/?fl=id&q=*:*&wt=xml&fq=alternate_names_manual:%22test%22&start=0&rows=1

schema.xml test 1

```
<fieldType name="commaDelimited" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=",\s*" />
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<field name="alternate_names_manual" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

data-config.xml test 1

```
<field name="alternate_names_manual" column="alternate_names_manual"/>
```

schema.xml test 2

```
<field name="alternate_names_manual" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_ss" type="strings"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

data-config.xml test 2

```
<field name="alternate_names_manual" column="alternate_names_manual" splitBy=","/>
```

How can I index and query comma separated values?

Comment: If you go to the analysis page of your Solr admin interface, you can see exactly how the text gets processed for each step in your analysis chain. It's also important to note the difference between the tokens being stored and the stored text being returned - an analysis chain will change the first, but not the second. Do you get any content in the field? Do you get a hit if you query with the complete value? (with commas intact)

Comment: Weird....my test 1 logic seems to work now, not sure why though. I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks!